# Getting error "The attachment content must be base64 encoded" while sending pdf in zip as an attachment using SendGrid

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, email-attachments, twilio-api, sendgrid-api-v3

We are using SendGrid latest available Java API to send emails. We are attaching a PDF enclosed in a zip file.

While sending mail we are getting a 404 response code and error message stating "The attachment content must be base64 encoded"

Complete Error Message:

```
{"errors":\[{"message":"The attachment content must be base64 encoded.","field":"attachments.0.content","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.attachments.content"}\]}
```

What are we doing wrong? How can we solve this issue and send this attachment? Here is the code where we try to send the PDF in a Zip.

Code:

```java
Path file = Paths.get(this.file.getAbsolutePath());
Attachments attachments = new Attachments();
attachments.setFilename(Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(file.getFileName().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
//attachments.setType``("application/pdf");
attachments.setDisposition("attachment");
byte[] attachmentContentBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
String attachmentContent = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(attachmentContentBytes);
attachments.setContent(attachmentContent);
mail.addAttachments(attachments);

com.sendgrid.SendGrid sg = new com.sendgrid.SendGrid(this.apiKey);
Request request = new Request();
request.setMethod(Method.POST);
request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
request.setBody(mail.build());
Response response = sg.api(request);
```

Response:

```
{"errors":\[{"message":"The attachment content must be base64 encoded.","field":"attachments.0.content","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.attachments.content"}\]}
```

Maven dependencies:

- com.sendgrid.sendgrid-java 4.9.1

Answer (score 4):

Try `Base64.getEncoder()` instead of `Base64.getMimeEncoder()`. Sometimes Sendgrid does not recognize the result from getMimeEncoder().

Comment: I've been banging my head on this for an hour! Thank you!!